# Bootstrap dropdown-toggle doesn't toggle

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-5

I'm at my wits end. I started up a new ASP.Net core web app and am trying to add a simple menu with a dropdown. However, the dropdown won't toggle open.

(And when is stackoverflow going to remove the ridiculous "issue" of you need more content to match the amount of code you're posting. Sometimes a question is short! Thanks!)

The dropdown:

```
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" asp-area="">Json</a>
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="LoadJson">Load Json</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="BulkLoadJson">Bulk Load Json</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

All the code in the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - DataMagnifierAdmin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/DataMagnifier_Admin.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">DataMagnifierAdmin</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="ExecETL">Execute ETL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" asp-area="">Json</a>
                            <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="LoadJson">Load Json</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="BulkLoadJson">Bulk Load Json</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - DataMagnifier_Admin - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `data-toggle="dropdown"` (Bootstrap 4) to `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` (Bootstrap 5).

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link text-dark dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" asp-area="">Json</a>
  <span class="caret"></span>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="LoadJson">Load Json</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="BulkLoadJson">Bulk Load Json</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: That's the problem. I would've had no idea. Thank you much, Cervus! I just discovered another bootstrap version issue, so I may be back for another question. :0) Is there some documentation that describes the changes from bootstrap 4 to 5? TIA

Comment: You're welcome. :) See documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/